# An exact ODE, trouble finding the integrating factor, choose b to drop out y.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

**I HAVE SOLVED THE EXERCISE.  I'M LIKELY TO WRITE AN ANSWER LATER**

The original question follows:

Find the value of b for which the differential equation below is exact.
$$(ye^{7xy}+x)dx+(bxe^{7xy})dy=0$$
Then solve it using that value of b.
An implicit solution is fine.  

My attempt uses
$$M=ye^{7xy}+x\text{ and } N= bxe^{7xy}$$

$ \frac{M_y-N_x}{M}= -\frac{7y}{b}+\frac{1}{bx}-\frac1x +7x$
I can use $b= \frac{1}{1+7x}$ to drop out the x's, but it reintroduces x's, in the term $\frac{7y}{b}=\frac{7y}{\frac{1}{1+7x}}$

Also, if b contains x's, when we take the partial, $N_x$ should I introduce $b_x$?  I'm working on dividing the original equation by b and will see what happens.  Then I'll take $M_y$, which is unaffected by b(x).   $ \frac{M_y-N_x}{M}$ hopefully will have b only in x terms.

Some context- I'm a tutor, with a B.S. in Math.  I don't have precise resources because this is for a student.  I did find an essentially identical problem in the Boyce, Diprima and Meade textbook, 11th edition, titled "Elementary Differential Equations and Boundary Value Problems".  Apparently, it comes from Section 2.6, page 89, problem number 12.  This is a first semester introductory course to ODE's.

Also, I'm having trouble googling these type of exercises because I get primarily simpler exact equations.  Is there a name for exact ODE equations based on $\frac{M_y-N_x}{M}$ or it's counterpart?

Comment: With $b=1$ this is exact without integrating factor.

Comment: hmmmm, really?  Wow, I've 4 pages of overcomplicating it.
My student kept insisting on using $\frac{M_y-N_x}{M}$ or the counterpart as part of finding the integrating factor.
I'll work it.  Can one sentence count as an answer?  LOL.

Comment: Comparing similar terms, one gets $...=\frac12d(x^2)+e^{7(xy)}d(xy)$. The mentioned formula is for integrating factors depending on $x$, while structurally here an integrating factor depending on $xy$ is needed.

Comment: Ohh, I caught a mistake.  I think my numerator cancels to zero now.

Comment: I get a constant for my integrating factor now.  hmmm, huh?

Comment: I'm reading it's exact *without* an integrating factor which makes sense to have $\mu = C$, but I don't think the text deals at all with integrating factors of two variables.  It specifically says it must be one variable.

Does it need an integrating factor of (xy) or how is it possible to integrate as is using b = 1?

Comment: Ahhh, I forgot the partial integral method for each coefficient, and creating them in such a way as to match.  Working on that now.

Comment: The general integration factor is a function of two variables leading to a PDE that is often more complicated than the original exact DE. That is why it was explored under what circumstances the integrating factor can be a scalar function. The argument of the scalar function can be anything, popular choices for text book exercises are $x$, $y$, $xy$, but that does by far not exhaust the possibilities.

Comment: I totally forgot the partial integral applied to each coeffecient.  I have the correct answer.  Thanks so much for your help.  You helped me catch two mistakes.
Should I write up my answer and post an answer to my own question?

Comment: Go ahead, I could only guess what exactly went wrong.ou know it and how you corrected it.